# How to post params using retrofit android studio?

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I need to send an array with Post Request using Retrofit. In Postman worked correctly like this
[image]

But in Android, I can not send the correct request.Please, help me.

**UPDATE**

I try like this:

```
 @POST("/api/friends")
fun getContactsList(@Header("Authorization") token String,@Query("phones[]") phones : Array<String>) : Single<List<Friends>>
```

Comment: Hello there option to send data using array can just confirm that what data your server side encoded so base on that we can construct from android and send to post request

Comment: The server side says that I should send an array and token in headers.  And I tried several options for sending an array, but I get a empty list.In Postman worked correctly.

Comment: have you tried to send post request using RequestBody

Comment: https://johnsonsu.com/android-retrofit-posting-array/ please check might be usefull for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
@POST("http://server/service")
Call<YourModel> postSomething(@Query("phones") List<String> array);
```

Generated url should look like this: 
`http://server/service?phones=123&phones=345&phones=567&phones=789`

Comment: Thank,for help me)))